# How to get presence of user in xmpp

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xmppframework

I am making a chat app with xmpp framework.

I have setup XMPPFramework in my project by referring this link:- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190

I have problem to get presence of roster in did receive presence.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream )sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence )presence
{

     DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);
     presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
     //myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
     presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
     //from = [[presence attributeForName:@"from"]stringValue];
     //type=[[presence attributeForName:@"type"]stringValue];
     NSLog(@"Present:%@",presenceType);
     NSLog(@"StatusUser:%@",presenceFromUser);

     [chlsttableview reloadData];

}
```

And in tableview I am showing presence of user as image of green or grey.

```
- (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      cl=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chtlistprototype" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      cl.fnm.text=[arrname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cl.fmsg.text=[arrid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cl.dpimg.image=img;
      NSUInteger a=[arrid indexOfObject:cl.fmsg.text];
      NSNumber *x=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:a];
      if ([arrid containsObject:presenceFromUser]&&[presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"])
      {
          for (int i=0; i<arrid.count; i++)
          {
              // NSIndexPath *path=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            if ([[arrid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:presenceFromUser])
            {
                 cl.stsimgvew.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
            }

        /*NSString gt=[arrid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSUInteger n=[arrid indexOfObject:gt];
         if (n==indexPath.row)
         {
         cl.stsimgvew.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
         }*/

        }
   }
return cl;
}
```

**So, my problem is that I am not getting proper presence image in tableview. I am getting one presence at a time and reloading table.
If i have 5 friends then did receive presence method will call 5 time for presence and then presence image will display only of last user.**

Comment: this is an example app which is completely working, go through this, it will help u a lot https://github.com/rayaleen/OpenFireClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-You will get from presence id of user on xmpp , which you can reflect in ur online status of your code

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    //XMPPPresence *online=[[XMPPPresence alloc]init];

    //[self xmppStream:xmppStream didReceivePresence:online];
    type=[[presence attributeForName:@"type"]stringValue];
    show_sts=[presence show];
    presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
}
```

Comment: How can we get this method called, As, This method is not call for me while any user go offline or Online. Is there any setting need to make in code or on server ?

Comment: May i know how to call this delegate method ? this method not get called simply user go for offline or online ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Wrapper` written in `Swift` around the `XMPPFramework`, it will simplify the development of a basic chat app, you will be notified when the `XMPPPresence` changes and there is an end-to-end tutorial to get you there.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios).